# Change DOM content through .firstChild property

Tags: javascript

I am trying to select an element by its relation with the rest of this DOM:

```
<div id="dad">
    <p>son</p>
    <p>son</p>
</div>
```

As seen here:

```
let daddy = document.getElementById('dad');
daddy.firstChild.textContent = "Im first";
```

What JS makes is, instead of changing its inner HTML, inserting the string as the first element of the 'dad' `<div>`.

This makes sense but, how can I make use of this property to select this first child and replace its content? Instead of inserting content as the element's first child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first child of `#dad` is a text node, because there are whitespaces between `<div id="dad">` and `<p>`. If you remove that whitespaces, it works fine:

```js
let daddy = document.getElementById('dad');
daddy.firstChild.textContent = "Im first";
```

```html
<div id="dad"><p>son</p><p>son</p></div>
```

Or you can use [`firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild) property:

```js
let daddy = document.getElementById('dad');
daddy.firstElementChild.textContent = "Im first";
```

```html
<div id="dad">
    <p>son</p>
    <p>son</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The children() method returns all direct children of the selected element.

This method only traverse a single level down the DOM tree.

```
$("#dad").children(":first").text("Im first");
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, loop through the child nodes until you find the first:

```js
let daddy = document.getElementById('dad');
var child = daddy.firstChild;
while(child && child.nodeType !== 1) child = child.nextSibling;
child.textContent = "Im first";
```

```html
<div id="dad">
    <p>son</p>
    <p>son</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is expected. This is because of text nodes which are a little less obvious than other elements. Looking at your html:

```
<div id="dad">
    <p>son</p>
    <p>son</p>
</div>
```

You have your `#dad` div, inside of which are 3 text nodes and 2 element notes. Can you spot the text nodes now? (hint, new lines and tabs are text). For this reason, many browsers now implement [`firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild).

You can also check to make sure the `nodeType === 1` before modifying it. You can read about the different [node types here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType). You can also remove all the white space, but this makes for hard to read code:

```
<div id="dad"><p>son</p><p>son</p></div>
```